# Develop a stochastic process into a stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

How can we write the following stochastic process $Xt=e^{-(Bt+t)^{2}}$ as stochastic itegral? Note that Bt is a standard BM. I'm guessing that we will need Itô's lemma to transform the expression, but I'm having a hard time to at least get started.

Comment: First you have to write $Y_t := (B_t+t)^2$ as an Itô process, i.e. you need to find a representation of the form $$dY_t = \sigma_t \, dB_t + b_t \, dt$$ (apply Itô's formula to do so). Once you have this you can apply Itô's formula (for Itô processes) to compute the stochastic differential of $e^{-Y_t}$.

Comment: Ok thank you for the tip. I was trying to apply Itô's formula to the whole $Xt$ exponential expression, which was giving me equations that were pretty hard to derivate. Now I think I'll manage.